# Node.js script runs with Forever but stops after around 30 minutes

Tags: node.js, socket.io

*I'm a web developer who is new to the whole "run your own (v)Server" so it might be a simple server problem I haven't figured out yet*

My problem is this: I'm running a simple Node.js *(0.6.6)* script on my vServer and I'm using "forever" to daemonize the script. The script checks for connecting sockets, increments a variable and sends the number to the user. If the sockets disconnects, the variable is decremented by one.

The script works fine, showing me around 100-200 "active" users **but after around 10-50 minutes, the script just stops working.** After the script stops, the vServer responds very slowly (at least I imagine that) - is it possible that my vServer is just too weak?

Here is the code:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8222);
var count = 0

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    count++;
    io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('message', {count: count});

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        count--;
    });
});
```

One last thing: I'm using a managed server for my project (from where the socket is opened) and a vServer from a different hoster for the node.js part.

Comment: I created a test script which only I connect to and every the seconds the server sends an update (the number of seconds I have been connected). Its running for more than three hours now, so I'm assuming that the problem with the other script was that there were too many users or the vServer was just too weak.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running `top` in a different window and watch the server load, see if it occurs the same time as when the server stops responding.